# Task.WhenAll never completes on exception

Tags: f#, task, task-parallel-library

I would expect this code to crash after 1 second, but it never terminates.

```ml
open System
open System.Threading.Tasks

let foo () =
  task {
    do! Task.Delay(1_000_000)

    return 1
  }

let bar () =
  task {
    do! Task.Delay(1_000)

    raise (Exception "KABOOM")

    return 3
  }

let main () =
  task {
    do! Task.Delay(100)

    let! results = Task.WhenAll(foo (), bar ())

    return Seq.sum results
  }

main ()
|> fun t -> t.Result
|> printfn "%i"
```

- What is happening here?
- Is there an alternative to `Task.WhenAll` that behaves as expected?

---

`Async` works as expected.

```ml
open System

let foo () =
  async {
    do! Async.Sleep(1_000_000)

    return 1
  }

let bar () =
  async {
    do! Async.Sleep(1_000)

    raise (Exception "KABOOM")

    return 3
  }

let main () =
  async {
    do! Async.Sleep(100)

    let! results = Async.Parallel([ foo (); bar () ])

    return Seq.sum results
  }

main ()
|> Async.RunSynchronously
|> printfn "%i"
```

Answer (score 1):

It does terminate with an exception, only after 1000 seconds - when `foo` terminates. That's how `Task.WhenAll` works, I don't see a way around it.

If you replace `task` with `async` (and `Task.WhenAll` with `Async.Parallel`, and `t.Result` with `Async.RunSynchronously`), then the behavior is exactly as you expect.

Yet another reason F# Async is superior to C# Task.

Comment: I was expecting `foo` to get interrupted once `bar` crashes. Async is a better fit here, yes.

Comment: @jdmneon `async` does work as expected.

Comment: My fault I made a mistake I thought this was in a different language

Answer (score 1):

This variant will fail fast on the first error:

```ml
open System
open System.Threading.Tasks

[<RequireQualifiedAccess>]
module Task =

  open System.Threading

  let whenAll (xs : #seq<Task<'a>>) : Task<'a array> =
    task {
      use cts = new CancellationTokenSource()

      let wrapTask (x : Task<'a>) =
        task {
          try
            let! result = x.WaitAsync(cts.Token)

            return result
          with exn ->
            cts.Cancel()

            return raise exn
        }

      let! results = Task.WhenAll(xs |> Seq.map wrapTask)

      return results
    }

let foo () =
  task {
    do! Task.Delay(100_000_000)

    return 1
  }

let bar () =
  task {
    do! Task.Delay(1_000)

    raise (Exception "KABOOM")

    return 3
  }

let main () =
  task {
    do! Task.Delay(100)

    let! results = Task.whenAll [ foo (); bar () ]

    return Seq.sum results
  }

main ()
|> fun t -> t.Result
|> printfn "%i"
```